# No events were found for the specified time range

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I am forwarding events to Azure Event Hub, and I want to process them in Stream Analytics. I have created a new Input that reads from this event hub and outputs to a table storage. When sampling data from the input I get the message:

**"No events were found in 'input' for the specified time range."**
[image]

But there are messages in the event hub:
[image]

I even created a simple project to query the same event hub, and it returns data:

```
258784  body: event=wsa1&data={"payloadtype": "pinvalue","pin": "D0","value": "1"}&published_at=2016-01-05T08:58:21.470Z&coreid=55ff6f066678530381667
259024  body: event=wsa1&data={"payloadtype": "pinvalue","pin": "D0","value": "1"}&published_at=201505530381667
259264  body: event=wsa1&data={"payloadtype": "pinvalue","pin": "D0","value": "2"}&published_at=2016-01-05T09:01:23.760Z&coreid=55ff6f0666785530381667
```

I have exactly the same solution working on another place. Don't understand why Stream Analytics is unable to see the data in Event Hub !? (testing the event hub connection works fine).

Comment: Most probably, the timeframe I was setting to sample data, was not for the data that was in the event hub ... things seem to be working now ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Event Hub. It seems like everything works fine, stream analytics, sampling, etc with IoT Hub only. I had the Azure IoT suite solutions deployed and using them I could pinpoint the problem to the event hub to stream analysis part.

Try IoT Hub instead of Event Hub and see if the issue persists. There are some advantages in using IoT Hub instead of Event Hub as well. Like bi-directional communication and device management.
See https://blog.tallan.com/2015/12/08/azure-iot-hub-vs-event-hub/.

I will try to update when I tried IoT Hub with in my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

When a user queries for sample data from eventhub input, ASA starts requesting for events with enqueued time greater than or equal to the time user mentioned. ASA waits for a limited time and returns the events it got from eventhub (upto a fixed  maximum). If there are no events in eventhub in the time range or if eventhub didn't return the events within the specified limit, you get above message.